# Left join with 3 tables where clause incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a JOIN across 3 tables with a `WHERE` clause, but I get an error:

> *'Incorrect syntax near '=' '.*

I dunno what I've got wrong ?

This is my statement :

```
select 
    TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME ,
    TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL , 
    TBL_CS_CLICKS.CLICK_COUNT 
from 
    TBL_CS_PROJECT 
left join 
    TBL_CS_LINKS on TBL_CS_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = TBL_CS_LINKS.PROJECT_ID 
right join 
    TBL_CS_CLICKS on TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_ID = TBL_CS_CLICKS.LINK_ID 
WHERE =  (CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0) 
    OR  (CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME) > 0) 
order by   
    TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `=` in the `WHERE` clause

```
...
WHERE (CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0)  OR ...
```

According to Docs: [CHARINDEX<sup>MSDN Doc</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

`CHARINDEX` - Searches an expression for another expression and returns its starting position if found.

This is already a boolean expression:

```
(CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0)
```

so your `WHERE` clause doesn't need `=` sign.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the expression after the `WHERE` clause to compare it to the expression `(CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0)` thats how the `=` operator works:

```
....
WHERE =  (CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0) 
OR  (CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME) > 0) order by   TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME
```

Remove the `=` operator :

```
   ...
   WHERE CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_LINKS.LINK_URL) > 0
     OR  CHARINDEX('t', TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME) > 0
   order by   TBL_CS_PROJECT.NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE =` is your problem. just change it to `WHERE`